# Magento 1.9.2.4 catalogrule_product_price is changed every time a price is updated

Tags: magento-1.9, price, catalog, catalog-price-rules

When a price is changed normally, the original price is displayed as a sale on the front end, and the new price is crossed out.

I've found that each time the price is changed, the **catalogrule_product_price** table is updated and holds onto the original price.
 Changing the latest rule entry in there will change the price on front end to what it should be. Has anyone run into this before?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue with this ended up being a bug related to Sweet Tooth, an extension for rewards. I contacted their tech support, and they gave me a [work-around](http://help.sweettoothrewards.com/article/403-setting-up-a-shopping-cart-earning-rule). We were using a catalog earning rule, and instead just changed it over to a shopping cart earning rule to avoid the confliction.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same exact situation.  Price rules stop displaying on category view pages after cron runs each time.  Then I re-apply rules then shows OK, then cron runs again and again price rule gone from category page but still shows on product page.

Still no solution.

Comment: Are you perhaps using sweet tooth for your store?